# Import file to struct stored in vector

Tags: c++, vector, struct, import, file-manipulation

I am having a program which basically employs the data structure struct inside vectors. But I am facing problems when importing data from file. Seems that it doesn't store as the way I expected to.

Thanks so much indeed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

//Declaration, and global variables

bool status_login = false, quit = false;

struct account {
    string id, pw;
    int win, ttl, best_time, best_move;
};

vector<account> vec;

struct account ac;

int total() {
    return vec.size();
};

//import

void import() {
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("mastermind.txt");
    if (fin.fail()) {
        cout << "Error opening file.";
            exit(1);
        }
    while (fin.good()) {
        getline(fin, ac.id);
        getline(fin, ac.pw);
        fin >> ac.win;
        fin >> ac.ttl;
        fin >> ac.best_time;
        fin >> ac.best_move;    
        fin.ignore (numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 
        vec.push_back(ac);
     }
    fin.close();
    cout << vec.size() << '\n' << vec[0].id << '\n';
}
```

mastermind.txt case 1:

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

mastermind.txt case 2:

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Expected results of respective cases will be:

```
1 //case1
1

2 //case2
1
```

What I have right now:

```
1 //case1

1 //case2
```

Thanks for helping a rookie who's really really so confused right now.

Comment: You need to show us the first few lines of `mastermind.txt`.

Comment: BTW: `total` can be written like this : `return vec.size();`, the `if` is useless.

Comment: @Jabberwocky That will be just some simple data ('id, pw, win, ttl, best_time, best_move') in separate lines.

Comment: Don't describe it, show it. You can [edit]  your question.

Comment: Edited. Is it clear enough? Thanks for your help indeed

Comment: It's better, but it's still not an example. We need to see the verbatime file that triggers the problem.

Comment: `while (fin.good())` is not quite as useful as you'd like. It tests the state of the stream BEFORE reading from it rather than after. That means some or all of the reading you do after the test could fail and you'll wind up putting garbage into the `vector`. It's better to do all of the reading in the `while`'s condition. That way the program doesn't enter the loop and won't add to the `vector` if any of the reads fail.

Comment: After `fin >> ac.best_move;` I believe there is still an unread newline in the input file so the next call to `getline` reads that. [cin and getline skipping input](//stackoverflow.com/a/10553849)

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for your kind answer, but how can I have the reading in 'while' when I read things more than once?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Edited for the sample files. Why will the output be deviated by the expected ones? Thank you so much.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Added the fin.ignore, what else do I need? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Side note: don't write your own file parsers. Just use some json or xml library. `nlohmann::json` has really clear c++ interface

Comment: Your code works as expected. What is your platform/IDE/Compiler/environnment? Where is your `main`  function? Is the program you're running the program you compile?

Comment: @CaseyChik Two ways: streams chain, so you can `fin >> ac.win >> ac.ttl >> etc...`. For things that do not chain there is  `&&`.